# Javascript truncating 0 from 05

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem in javascript. I have two select boxes, one for hours and one for minutes. When the user selects the time then the AM/PM should automatically be set.

Can anyone help me??? I have tried this code:

**CODE:**

```
<select class="cust_ddd3" id="phr" onchange="hors(this.value)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>

<select class="cust_ddd2" id="pmns" onchange="mns(this.value);">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
</select>

Pickup Time: <span id="hrs">08</span>:<span id="mns">00</span><span id="ap">AM</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hors(str)
{
  document.getElementById('hrs').innerHTML=+str;
}

function mns(str)
{
  alert(str);
  if(document.getElementById('phr').value<=11)
  {
    var pm="AM";
    document.getElementById('ap').innerHTML=pm;
  }
  else
  {
    var am="PM";
    document.getElementById('ap').innerHTML=am;
  }
  document.getElementById('mns').innerHTML=+str;
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are approaching wrong way. by above way, only when user select `12` then it will change `AM` to `PM`

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. You have no way of knowing whether it's AM or PM just by having the user select 1-12.

Comment: if your are generating so long selectbox for hours and minutes then why don't u create one more select box to choose from `AM` and `PM` or make 2 Radio button

Answer (score 0):

When you convert the minutes to number in

```
document.getElementById('mns').innerHTML=+str;
```

The first zero is discarded (normal numbers don't have leading zeroes).

Answer (score 0):

The error is here document.getElementById('mns').innerHTML=+str;. You are using the +=, while you should be using +=, or =:

```
document.getElementById('mns').innerHTML = str;
```

The =+ converts the string to a number (and therefore, ignoring the zeros on the left) and then adding the result to the original value

Comment: And when using it make sure it is `+=` not `=+`